# Indent Code In Haskell

Tags: haskell

I know that indent is important in Haskell. How can i indent this program?

```
qsort [] =[]
qsort (x:xs) = let bigsorted = [a| a<-xs,a>=x]
       smallsorted= [a| a<-xs,a<x]
       in qsort bigsorted ++ [x] ++ smallsorted
```

I am using the vim editor. Is there any way in which the program can be automatically indented?

Comment: It seems you need to "qsort" "smallsorted" as well to get an actual quick sort implementation ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here smallsorted is not a part of the let block.

```
qsort [] =[]
qsort (x:xs) = let bigsorted = [a| a<-xs,a>=x]
                   smallsorted= [a| a<-xs,a<x]
                in qsort bigsorted ++ [x] ++ smallsorted
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple rule to remember is to indent the items of some group further to the right than the beginning of this group. For example, let's take a look on let-bindings group:

```
let
  x = 2 + 3 -- this line is indented further than "let" which starts the group.
  y = x + x -- next lines are usually indented on the same level
```

Another example is do-block:

```
do
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
```

More details can be found in Haskell wiki: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation

In your example "smallSorted" was indented less than the beginning of let-group, thus it was not recognized as a part of let-group.

Semi-automatical indentation is present in Emacs haskell-mode. Actually there are three different modes for indentation, but none works really well, since it is not easy to disambiguate what user really means. More detail again on Haskell wiki: 
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs#Indentation

Answer (score 5):

```
qsort []     = []
qsort (x:xs) = 
  let bigsorted   = [a | a <- xs, a >= x]
      smallsorted = [a | a <- xs, a < x]
  in  qsort bigsorted ++ [x] ++ smallsorted
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a stylistic thing - if you like to write your code in that format (as I do), you can use `where`, though that means you also need to place your final expression at the start rather than at the end.

```
qsort [] =[]
qsort (x:xs) = qsort bigsorted ++ [x] ++ smallsorted where
       bigsorted = [a| a<-xs,a>=x]
       smallsorted= [a| a<-xs,a<x]
```